# How to remove SP3 from XP

Tags: windows-xp, sp3

How to remove SP3 from XP, it's installed with OS image, it's not installed separately...

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you want to remove it? (nothing bad implied, just curious)

Comment: I hope you're doing this just to create some kind of test platform.  Running XP after 9 years is bad enough.  XP without updates is just awful.

Answer (score 8):

You can't. If the OS shipped with SP3 slipstreamed (pre-installed), then there's nothing you can do short of finding an OS installation disc that does not have this slipstreamed and re-installing your OS.